# Cordova/Phonegap Blackberry filetransfer download

Tags: file-io, blackberry, cordova

I would like to figure out how to download an image and display it in phonegap app on Blackberry (for iOS and Android I already managed to do so). As a test I'm using [Simon's example](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/04/sorry-for-being-gone-so-long-vacation.html) attached below.

If I run the example on playbook using  [WebWorks method](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20BlackBerry) it sims to run without any errors (non are reported in WebInspector) but the image is not displayed. Although that the file transfer sims successful and the reported entry.fullPath is 
file:///accounts/1000/appdata/....../data//doubt.jpg there is something wrong with accessing file on this path. Looking at requests in Network tab (WebInspector) it shows
that size of the file that is being requested at the local image path is only 15B. It looks like this is the empty file created when we called fileSystem.root.getFile and not the file that should have been saved in this path when transfered from server.

I'm trying to resolve this for a couple of days now, with no success only frustration.  I found suggestions for using blackberry.io.sharedFolder of blackberry.io.home to declare the path where the file should be saved but although I have blackberry object the blackberry.io.sharedFolder and home are undefined.

I also tried the same example on Blackberry z10 with NDK method, but in this case the entry.fullPath is local:///persistent/.. but then the file can not be accessed from this path (GET error is reported). Also there is no blackberry object available in this case.

So I think the basic question is what local path should be set for the file download so that the file will then be accessible trough URI.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  
        }
    </style>
  <script src="cordova/cordova.BBplaybook.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">       
    function init(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, true);     
    }

    function ready() {

    }

    function download() {
      console.log("calling download");
    //    // blackberry.io.sandbox = false;
    // console.log("blackberry.io.sharedFolder");
    //   console.log(blackberry.io.sharedFolder);
    //   console.log("blackberry");
    //   console.log(blackberry);

        var remoteFile = "http://i3.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/000/080/doubt.jpg";
        var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        console.log("localFileName");
      console.log(localFileName);

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

            fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
                console.log("localPath");
                console.log(localPath);

                if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
                    localPath = localPath.substring(7);
                }
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.download(remoteFile,
                    localPath, function(entry) {
                        var dwnldImg = document.getElementById("dwnldImg");
                        dwnldImg.src = entry.fullPath;
                        console.log("entry.fullPath;");
                         console.log(entry.fullPath);
                        dwnldImg.style.visibility = "visible";
                        dwnldImg.style.display = "block";
                    }, fail);
            }, fail);


        }, fail);
    }

    function fail(error) {
      console.log("error");
      console.log(error);
        console.log(error.code);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
    <button onclick="download()" >Download and display image</button>
    <img src="" id="dwnldImg" style="display: none"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In config.xml I have

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="*" />
<feature id="blackberry.io.file" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
<feature id="blackberry.utils" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
<feature id="blackberry.io.dir" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />

<rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
```

and plugins.xml

```
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileManager"/>
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.http.FileTransfer"/>
```

Comment: After doing a similar example in pure WebWorks on BB10, I believe there is noting wrong with local paths that are used in the above cordova example. The problem must then be with FileTransfer.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this, wideblue?

Comment: @MattGrande I gave up and used pure WebWorks for BB10 instead of phone-gap. The port was quite easy.